# I want to implement who visited your profile

Tags: sql, postgresql, relational-database

For my project I am using postgresql as database.

I have **users** table which contains (**user_id, username, full name, email, token, gender**)

I have another table called **views** which has field of (**views_id, from_user_id, to_user_id, date_created**)

Now I want to implement visit history (like linkedin) in the user profile. Visit history means who visited my profile and If I consult another user profile it must appear in my visit history as well.

Let's say, my username is *mhasan*. Now, I need a query which query result could be like this

| to_visit_username | from_visit_username |
| --- | --- |
| *AAA* | *mhasan* |
| *BBB* | *mhasan* |
| *mhasan* | *ZZZ* |

Could anyone help me to write the appropriate query to get the above result? Or is there any other easiest way to do that? Any kind of suggestion is appreciatable.

Comment: Presumably this is just a `join` or two.  What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `JOIN` the `VIEWS` table with two `USERS` table as follows:

```
Select t.username to_visit_username, 
       F.username from_visit_username
  From views v
  Join users t on v.to_user_id = t.user_id
  Join users f on v.from_user_id = f.user_id
 Where 'mhasan' in (f.username, t.username)
```

Comment: It seems to be a good solution. But this query complains **ERROR:  column f.from_user_id does not exist
LINE 5:   Join users f on f.from_user_id = t.user_id
                          ^
HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column "v.from_user_id".**

Comment: Yeap, changed the aliases in ON conditions. Check now!!